# HTTP client not working for retrieving content from e-commerce website

Tags: http, curl, rust

I am trying to implement a web page watcher in Rust. Basic idea is that when certain string is not found in the page content, I would get a notification.

The basic logic is working for most situations but for certain e-commerce site (argos.co.uk in this case), it always return a page with "You don't have permission to access" in it.

The same page, of course, works fine with Safari. So I did `Copy as cURL` which gave me the following:

```
-X 'GET' \
-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.2 Safari/605.1.15'
```

Running the copied cURL command works fine as expected. So I added those 2 headers in to my Rust code:

```
let cli = reqwest::Client::new();
let resp = cli
    .get(url)
    .header(USER_AGENT, r#"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.2 Safari/605.1.15"#)
    .header(ACCEPT, r#"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"#)
    .send().await?;
```

And I still got the same "you don't have permission..." page as above.

Using the above code with `httpbin.org/get` shows that Rust reqwest is indeed sending the right header. So I am at lost where to look for next. What could have gone wrong in my situation?

**EDIT**

I tried using the `cURL` command with httpbin as suggested below and got the following back.

```
   "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.2 Safari/605.1.15",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-62011d4b-5ea67cec2c79826d5d00e959"
```

I don't believe `X-Amzn-Trace-Id` was sent by `cURL` but am more than willing to be proven wrong.

Comment: Does the web site you're trying to reach require a login an password?

Comment: Try the `curl` version against `httpbin.org/get` and carefully compare the complete set of request headers against those issued by your Rust app.  What differences are there?  Maybe Rust is sending some headers that `curl` isn't, or vice-versa; or maybe there's some difference in the content of some header(s) sent by both?

Comment: This kind of error is commonly associated with anti-bot protection - based on the IP address of the site it is protected by Akamai. Note that curl sends more headers than just the two you gave and reqwest likely too. Anti-bot protection might not only look at the existence and value of the specific headers you gave but also at other headers you did not gave and at the order or spelling of headers.

Comment: @Jmb no. The page is not protected.

Comment: @eggyal I've added `curl` result above

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I've added `curl` result above

Comment: @lang2: what curl actually sends can be simply checked with `curl -v`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested, this is most likely a basic header validation to prevent scraping. The following works for me:

```
use std::error::Error;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let cli = reqwest::Client::new();
    let resp = cli
        .get("https://www.argos.co.uk/product/<YOUR_ID>")
        .header(reqwest::header::ACCEPT, "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8")
        .header(reqwest::header::ACCEPT_ENCODING, "identity")
        .header(reqwest::header::ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, "en-US,en;q=0.5")
        .header(reqwest::header::USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0")
        .send().await?;

    println!("{:?}", resp.status());
    println!("{}", resp.text().await?);

    Ok(())
}
```

Note that I've switched `Accept-Encoding` from `gzip` to `identity`. You can (and most likely should) use the [gzip feature](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.ClientBuilder.html#method.gzip).

And of course make sure to respect the `robots.txt` and usage terms in regards to scraping.

Comment: Thanks. It does work. Although I am still entirely clear as what `curl` has sent.

Comment: I checked with `-vv` and it didn't show any header other than `accept` and `user-agent`. But `curl` did sent HTTP/2 request. So perhaps I'll check that as well.